Why does npm run electron:serve fail to render the app in localhost?
I have an Electron + Vue project,
and I’m trying to run the application using the localhost URL (http://localhost:8080/) in Chrome.
However, the app doesn't render and throws the following error message in the browser console:
Error Message:
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.events (app.js:1638:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1786:32)
    at fn (app.js:2035:21)
    at eval (emitter.js:1:20)
    at ./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js (chunk-vendors.js:5925:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1786:32)
    at fn (app.js:2035:21)
    at eval (reloadApp.js:5:80)
    at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js (chunk-vendors.js:5199:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1786:32)

Here is my index.html file and the screenshot of the error:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">    
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app">123</div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>While the application runs fine in Electron itself, it fails to render when accessing localhost in Chrome.

enter image description here Can't render app context
While the application runs fine in Electron itself, it fails to render when accessing localhost in Chrome.
I’m looking for help to resolve this issue.
I try to 3 methods,but still same result.
1.background.ts add...
win.loadURL("http://localhost:8080");
mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');

2.background.ts set nodeIntegration and contextIsolation
const win = new BrowserWindow({
width: 800,height: 600,
webPreferences: {
preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
nodeIntegration: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
contextIsolation: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",},});

3.background.ts import...
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from "electron";
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", {require: (module) => require(module),});

